# Improving Cmd-` app window switching - MRU order and/or preview

Tags: window-manager, application-switcher

Using the Cmd-` shortcut to switch between windows in an application is inefficient for me when there are more than two windows since they are cycled through in a fixed order and there is little visual feedback to show which window has been switched to. Is there a way to change the behavior so that it works more like Cmd-Tab? Specifically, I would like to be able to switch between windows in most recently used order and/or display an icon or preview to show the window being switched to.

I'm using OS X 10.7.5.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Task Switching with the Keyboard](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54788/task-switching-with-the-keyboard)

Comment: @Mark Let's leave it open. Neither is a general OS X question and one is for Lion and the other for Snow Leopard. Linking them together is excellent - thanks for that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an app called witch.

http://manytricks.com/witch/

It allows cmd+` switching using MRU order and a popup overlay similar to the default cmd+tab overlay. You can also, optionally, show window previews and many other customizations.